# How submit iphone application on Appstore and what are prerequirement?

Tags: iphone, ios

I create my first iphone app now i want submit this on appstore so please tell me what are prerequirement and step by step process. And also recommend links.

Comment: Not a programming related Question !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) regarding asking questions. Please also search before posting a question. This type of question has been asked MANY times before. Apple also provide you with all the information you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best tutorial i can suggest you..Follow all the steps in this tutorial.
 http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-create-distribution-build-with.html

Answer (score 1):

reffer to this http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-a-step-by-step-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Just watch the WWDC 2012 session [Building, Archiving, and Submitting Your App](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=414).

Answer (score 0):

All the instructions you need are right there on the [iOS provisioning portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/distribution/index.action).